# Joining seperate SpatialPolygons within a list in R

Tags: r, join, spatial, shapefile, r-sp

This is an example of a list with two separate (not adjacent or overlapping) SpatialPolygons and I would like to join them into one shapefile. For some reason no matter what I try I keep getting an error:

```
library(sp)

coords = matrix(c(78.46801, 19.53407,
                  78.46801, 19.74557,
                  78.83157, 19.74557,
                  78.83157, 19.53407,
                  78.46801, 19.53407), 
                ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)


P1 = Polygon(coords)
Ps1 = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(P1), ID = "a")), proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))


coords2 = matrix(c(77.46801, 17.53407,
                  77.46801, 17.74557,
                  77.83157, 17.74557,
                  77.83157, 17.53407,
                  77.46801, 17.53407), 
                ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)


P2 = Polygon(coords2)
Ps2 = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(P2), ID = "a")), proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))

P_list <- list(Ps1,Ps2)

joined = SpatialPolygons(lapply(P_list, function(x){x@polygons[[1]]}))
Error in validObject(res) : 
  invalid class “SpatialPolygons” object: non-unique Polygons ID slot values
```

Comment: Change the Ps2 `ID` param to 'b' or something else (not 'a' again). You can also join the two polygons using `rbind` don't need to use `lapply(P_list,...)`. And there is an error in the allocation to P2.  I assume it should be `P2 = Polygons(coords2)`

Comment: Perfect, thank you for spotting the issue! it works beautifully with rbind.

Comment: @AlvaroFranquet any idea why `rbind(P_list[[1]],P_list[[2]])` works while `lapply(P_list, rbind)` does not?

Comment: Ok, I figured this will work `do.call(rbind,P_list)`